# stackdriver query throws 400 GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request "Request contains an invalid argument"

Tags: logging, google-api, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have the following query for stackdriver logs

`resource.labels.jsonPayload.kubernetes.pod_name=test-deployment-5c58c774b-tcdbq AND jsonPayload.env="dev" AND jsonPayload.kubernetes.namespace_name=filter-platform AND jsonPayload.kubernetes.labels."app.kubernetes.io/name"=gateway AND timestamp>="2020-01-21T17:58:00Z" AND timestamp<"2020-01-21T17:59:00Z"`

This throws 400 with the following response

`GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "code" : 400, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.", "reason" : "badRequest" } ], "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.", "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT" }`

When i remove the pod_name filter like below then the query works. Any idea what is wrong in the way i am trying to filter with pod_name along with other parameters?

`jsonPayload.env="dev" AND jsonPayload.kubernetes.namespace_name=filter-platform AND jsonPayload.kubernetes.labels."app.kubernetes.io/name"=gateway AND timestamp>="2020-01-21T17:58:00Z" AND timestamp<"2020-01-21T17:59:00Z"`

The above query works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set the new [Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/migration#resource_type_changes) on your cluster, the way to filer the pod name should be as followin:

resource.labels.pod_name="POD_NAME"

This should show you the pod that you are trying to review.